# Git Commit Error

Tags: git, version-control

I'm brand new to Git and totally frustrated with it. I'm using Eclipse in Windows. I've imported from a repository and made a few changes. Now I want to send these changes back to the repository. From the reading that I have done (and I have done a lot of it), I understand that I need to commit these changes. Next to the name of my project, I can see an up arrow and the number 1 inside of brackets.

So, I right click on the project name, select Team and then Commit. Then I get this error:

> Error computing diffs  Missing tree

followed by a hex string.

I am at a total loss. I've tried doing this through github.com and through the windows desktop application. Nothing works. Can somebody please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with Eclipse rather than git: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/724188/

Answer (score 1):

Use MSysGit on the command line. For day to day use, IDE Git integration is overrated. You will have a history of what you did (no need to remember what menu item you chose or what button you pressed in the toolbar), piping, scriptability and tab completion. You get none of those benefits out of an ide integrated SCM tool.

Also, using Git the way it was intended to be used, from the command line, you will find more help on line than you will for some other way.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after windows update installed updates but without restarting the computer. After a restart, it all worked again.